The Dimensions of my components change unexpectedly when I reload the application
I am currently developing a React Native application using Expo, and I've encountered a perplexing issue related to the rendering of components on a Lenovo tablet device. The core of the problem lies in the unexpected change in dimensions of certain components when the app is refreshed. Interestingly, temporarily altering any styling value of the affected component seems to rectify the issue until the next refresh, at which point the dimensions go awry again. Reverting the styling changes does not cause the problem to reoccur immediately; it only resurfaces upon reloading the application.
This issue was initially observed with a Modal component, but it has since appeared in other parts of the application, leading me to suspect a more systemic problem, possibly related to the way my App.js is structured or executed. Despite various attempts to diagnose and fix the issue, including reviewing component hierarchies and styling logic, the problem persists, suggesting it might be influenced by specific behaviours of the React Native framework or the Expo environment on the Lenovo tablet.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can offer insights into potential causes or solutions? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
App.js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer, getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute  } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation'
import ReadingCatalogue from './Components/Screens/Stacks/ReadingCatalogue';


import Home from './Components/Screens/BottomTabs/Home';
import ExampleScreen from './Components/Screens/Stacks/ExampleScreen';
import SomethingElse from './Components/Screens/BottomTabs/SomethingElse';
import CameraScreen from './Components/Displays/CameraScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const getTabBarVisibility = (route) => {
  const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? '';
  console.log("Current route name:", routeName);

  return !['CameraScreen'].includes(routeName);
}


function StackNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeTab" component={TabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false}} name="CameraScreen" component={CameraScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ExampleScreen" component={ExampleScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="ReadingCatalogue" component={ReadingCatalogue} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function TabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({route}) => ({
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        height : "6%",

      },
      tabBarStyle : {
        display: getTabBarVisibility(route) ? "none" : "flex",
      }  
    })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="SomethingElse" component={SomethingElse} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};




export default function App() {
  const [orienation, setOrientation] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    LockOrientation();
  }, []);

  const LockOrientation = async () => {
    await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE);
    const o = await ScreenOrientation.getOrientationAsync();
    setOrientation(o);
  };

  return (
    <PaperProvider>
    <NavigationContainer>
     <StackNavigator />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});


Below is where I am rendering the Carousel ReadingCatalogue.js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import ReadingCarousel from '../../Displays/ExtractCarousel/ReadingCarousel'

const ReadingCatalogue = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.pageHeader}>What Would You Like To Read?</Text>
      <ReadingCarousel/>
    </View>
  )
}

export default ReadingCatalogue

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  pageHeader:{
    fontSize: 60,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
    padding: 30,
  }
})

The code snippets below are all the files related to the carousel.
ReadingCarouselItem.js
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions,} from "react-native"
import React from 'react'

export const SLIDER_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width + 80
export const ITEM_WIDTH = Math.round(SLIDER_WIDTH * 0.4)


const ReadingCarouselItem = ({item, index}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container} key={index}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>{item.title}</Text>
      <View style={styles.something}>
      <Text>{item.difficultyLevel}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.somethingText}>{item.category}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>

  )
}

export default ReadingCarouselItem

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 8,
    width: ITEM_WIDTH,
    height: '50%',
    paddingBottom: 5,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 3,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.29,
    shadowRadius: 4.65,
    elevation: 7,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },

  header: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 10,
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 70,
  },

  something: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
    zIndex: 100,
    padding: 10,
    opacity: 0.7,
  },

  somethingText:{
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
  }
})

ReadingCarousel.js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel'
import ReadingCarouselItem, { ITEM_WIDTH, SLIDER_WIDTH } from './ReadingCarouselItem'  
import ExtractCatalogue from '../../../ExtractCatalogue'

const ReadingCarousel = () => {
    const isCarousel = React.useRef(null)

  return (
    <View>
        <Carousel
        layout='default'
        layoutCardOffset={9}
        ref={isCarousel}
        data={ExtractCatalogue}
        renderItem={ReadingCarouselItem}
        sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
        itemWidth={ITEM_WIDTH}
        inactiveSlideShift={0}
        useScrollView={false}
        />
    </View>
   
  )
}

export default ReadingCarousel

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

Some Pictures for context about what is happening


In attempting to resolve the unexpected component dimension changes upon app refresh, I have taken several steps to diagnose and potentially correct the issue. Here are the key actions I've undertaken:
Introduction of Paper Provider: Considering I hadn't used the Paper Provider component in previous projects, I thought it might be influencing the issue. However, integrating and configuring it did not resolve the problem, indicating that the cause lies elsewhere.
Orientation Lock: Given that my application is designed for a Lenovo tablet primarily in landscape mode, I ensured the orientation was locked to landscape. Despite this, I observed that the Expo app, particularly the QR code scan section, seems optimized for mobile phones and defaults to portrait mode. Modifying the approach to orientation locking did not alleviate the issue, suggesting that orientation constraints might not be directly related to the component dimension changes.
Exploring Styling Issues: Initially, when the problem presented itself with a Modal component, I presumed it was a styling-related issue. This led me to meticulously review and adjust styles, which temporarily fixed the problem upon any change but did not offer a permanent solution. When encountering the same issue on a completely new screen, without any apparent styling influence from other components, it reaffirmed my belief that the problem might be more complex and possibly related to the application's foundational setup or interaction with the React Native framework in this specific device context.
Through these steps, I aimed to narrow down the potential causes but have yet to identify a definitive solution to the component dimension instability upon app refreshes. The temporary fixes through styling adjustments hint at a deeper, perhaps systemic issue within the app's architecture or its interaction with the React Native/Expo environment on this specific device.

I have a feeling its something to do with the orientation and how Dimensions is being used 'export const SLIDER_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width + 80'
'export const ITEM_WIDTH = Math.round(SLIDER_WIDTH * 0.7)'
I feel like despite locking the application to landscape its still reading the portrait screen values which is what is squishing my elements.

I fixed it, I was right about the dimensions issue. I believe this is happening because the application is grabbing all the values as soon as the app launches and is loading(which should). The problem with that is it was taking the values from portrait mode because Expo go starts in portrait. Which is why when I updated a random value after the reload it correct the issue temporarily. I added an even Listener to look out for changes in the orientation and update the values. So it happened after the app loads and swaps in to locked landscape.
